# Why does my profile say I have no questions asked and one bronze when there should be more?

Tags: discussion

I suspect I do not understand the mechanics of the Q&A system here - but it is puzzling just the same.

This morning I had 21 reputation and three bronze, while now I see 21 reputation and one bronze - and No questions asked - while I asked my first question on 11 or 12 January. (Actually I thought my reputation might have been 31, but very unsure now - not really something I am overly concerned about).

re: the bronze I am sure because at the bottom of my profile page it does say 21 reputation and 3 bronze.

Maybe the answer is "C'est la vie" :)

So, if you are able - please explain the mechanics. I suppose I could do a better search of the site - but you do not get reputation points for not asking it seems. And now I must also hope no negative points for asking a (potentially) duplicate question.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on Meta Ask Ubuntu, Ask Ubuntu's meta site where we discuss the site's policies and the site itself. Badges and posts are separate from the [main site](https://askubuntu.com/users/367698/michael-felt).

Take a look at the [help center article](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta) on meta for more detailed information.

Comment: So easy to get lost :) Thanks!